Blink sample in DA14531 - Jlink errors
I am trying to build the Blink sample for the DA14531 with Jlink, but I get Error messages related to LTO. How to solve this error?  use of LTO is disallowed in this variant of Arm Compiler for Embedded
I haven't tried more.

if you are using keil 5
go to "option for target" then "C/C++" section, next uncheck the "Link-Time Optimation" (LTO) option.
good luck :)
